# How to get nested info from Firebase Database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

So we are using a Firebase Database to store our data, however I'm having quite some issues fetching the data from the database. This is the structure we are using.

```
candles
   $userId
      $senderId
        candleName
          name
          quote
```

The question I have is how do I get the `name` and `quote` of every sender of a specific `userId`.

When there is a sender with multiple candles, I don't know how to loop through the code, I was thinking about nesting a `ngFor` loop but I think that's not that performant. Below you can see a `console.log` of the objects I get from Firebase.

[image]

Comment: make use of pipes that will help

Comment: What pipes do you mean?

Comment: Angular pipes more on the same can be found here [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/pipes)

Answer (score 0):

After the first for loop I was iterating over keys and values so that's what went wrong!

I'm using `Object.keys()` to iterate over my objects' keys and values!